# R How to create several variables containing substring characters

Tags: r, substr

My datafile contains a variable with responses to several questions.

The structure is:

```
ID response
1  BCCAD
2  ABCCD
3  BA.DC
.....
```

I want to separate each response in a new variable, q1, q2, ..:

```
ID q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  B  C  C  A  D
2  A  B  C  C  D
3  B  A  .  D  C
....
```

I tried the following code

```
 v <- rep("q",5)
 z <- as.character(1:5)
 paste(v,z,sep="")
 for(i in 1:20){
 f[i]<- substr(response,i,i)
 }
```

But it only replace the variable names in the vector.

What I intend is to create as many variables as needed to store the values for each question. Variable should be named with a common root, "q", and a subscript showing the position within the string.

Comment: Also, something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(response, "")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several other options:

**1)** The `separate` function from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
# notation 1:
separate(d, col=response, into=paste0('q',1:5), sep=1:4)
# notation 2:
d %>% separate(col=response, into=paste0('q',1:5), sep=1:4)
```

**2)** The `tstrsplit` function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, paste0('q',1:5) := tstrsplit(response, split = '')][, response := NULL][]
```

**3)** The `cSplit` function of `splitstackshape` in combination with `setnames` from `data.table`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
setnames(cSplit(d, 'response', sep='', stripWhite=FALSE), 2:6, paste0('q',1:5))[]
```

which all give the same result:

```
  ID q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  1  B  C  C  A  D
2  2  A  B  C  C  D
3  3  B  A  .  D  C
```

---

Used data:

```
d <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, response = c("BCCAD", "ABCCD", "BA.DC")), .Names = c("ID", "response"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strsplit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) function :

```
DF <- 
read.csv(text="ID,response
1,BCCAD
2,ABCCD
3,BA.DC",header=TRUE)

DF2 <- cbind(DF['ID'], do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(DF$response),"")))

names(DF2)[-1] <- paste0('q',1:(ncol(DF2)-1))

> DF2
  ID q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  1  B  C  C  A  D
2  2  A  B  C  C  D
3  3  B  A  .  D  C
```

Please note that this works only if all the strings in response column have the same number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
df=data.frame(ID=1:3,response=c("BCCAD","ABCCD","BA.DC"))
response.split <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",lapply(split(df$response,df$ID),FUN=function(vec){strsplit(as.character(vec),"")[[1]]})))
names(response.split) <- paste("q",1:ncol(response.split),sep="")
out <- cbind(ID=df$ID,response.split)
out

  ID q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  1  B  C  C  A  D
2  2  A  B  C  C  D
3  3  B  A  .  D  C
```